# Tapping Enter in image uploader cause the edit to be submitted

Tags: bug, mobile-web, uploader

Tapping <kbd>Enter</kbd> when adding image via URL in mobile web leads to submitting a post instead of adding an image.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Switch to mobile web.
2. Open already existing post for edit (for prevent new post restrictions).
3. Try to add image from URL by typing and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

> [image: image by link]

3. Instead of adding an image, edit will be submitted.

I suppose pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in this situation should work as "Add picture" button, but doesn't.